# How can I share session data between Dancer2 apps with different serializers?

Tags: perl, dancer

I am trying to migrate an app from Dancer to Dancer2.  My thought is to separate the code into routes that are served with templates and those that are Ajax (API) calls.

My base app is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin; 
use Plack::Builder;

use Routes::Templates;
use Routes::Login; 

builder {
    mount '/'    => Routes::Templates->to_app;
    mount '/api' => Routes::Login->to_app;
};
```

I was thinking that the `Routes::Templates` package would not have any serializer and the `Routes::Login` package would have JSON serialization.   I used

```
set serializer => 'JSON';
```

in the `Routes::Login` package.

However, I also want these to share session data so each has a common appname

```
use Dancer2 appname => 'myapp';
```

in each file. And that appears to run into trouble with the serialization. The `Routes::Template` routes are not returning correctly because it is trying to be encoded as JSON.  Here's the error:

> Failed to serialize content: hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this)

I've read all the documentation, including these:

- [How can I use Dancer2::Plugin::Database when my code is split into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012789/how-can-i-use-dancer2plugindatabase-when-my-code-is-split-into-multiple-file)
- https://github.com/wyoung/advent-calendar/tree/master/danceradvent/public/articles/2015

But I'm still not clear on how the serializer is separated by package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to combine your apps using `appname`; session data will be shared as long as both apps use the same configuration for the session engine. (Also, [serializers are an all-or-nothing prospect](http://advent.perldancer.org/2014/11) in Dancer2, so you really *have* to use two separate apps.)

Here's the example I gave on the [dancer-users mailing list](http://lists.preshweb.co.uk/pipermail/dancer-users/2015-March/004457.html):

**MyApp/lib/MyApp.pm**

```
package MyApp;
use Dancer2;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    session foo => 'bar';
    template 'index';
};

true;
```

**MyApp/lib/MyApp/API.pm**

```
package MyApp::API;
use Dancer2;

set serializer => 'JSON';

get '/' => sub {
    my $foo = session('foo') // 'fail';
    return { foo => $foo };
};

true;
```

**MyApp/bin/app.psgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";

use MyApp;
use MyApp::API;
use Plack::Builder;

builder {
    mount '/'    => MyApp->to_app;
    mount '/api' => MyApp::API->to_app;
};
```

If you access the `/` route followed by the `/api` route in the same browser, you'll get

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

indicating that the same session variable was used by both requests.

Comment: [Dancer2::Plugin::SendAs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::SendAs) allows you to override the default all-or-nothing serializer behavior, but it's not necessary here, and I think things are cleaner when you do stick to one serializer for all routes in an app.

Comment: I got this to work in the test case and am applying it to mine.  I wanted to add that to get a test script to get this to work, you need to make sure that you save cookies and the resend as shown in [the Dancer doc on testing with cookies](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual/Testing.pod#Cookies)